# Entity Framework database defaults on inserts allow updates

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to have entity framework use a SQL default value on an insert and yet allow updating to the field.  We have an instance where a SQL table has an identity column "id" and another column which is set to ident_current("table").  The only way that I know of to get the field inserted with the default value is to set the field as `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)` so that it is ignored on the insert.  However by having that attribute then we cannot perform an update to the column.  Also it's a self referencing foreign key so we can't do an insert then immediate update to get around the issue.  Don't ask me why the table is designed this way - just the way it was set up before so we're kind of stuck with it for now.  A simple diagram of our setup is below:

DomainClass:

```
Class1 {
     public int id {get;set;}
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
     public int id2 {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

SQL (pseudo):

```
Table (
    id INT  which is an identity(1,1) column,
    id2 INT NOT NULL with a default value of ident_current("table")
    Name nvarchar(50)
)
```

We would want the insert statement generated by EF to be:

```
INSERT INTO Table(Name) VALUES('Name')
```

and the update to be:

```
UPDATE table 
SET id2 = *somenumber*, name = 'Name'
```

Thanks a lot for all the help. We are using EF 4.3.1.0 if that's needed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way AFAIK. See [this](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2541076-allow-using-sql-server-2012-sequence-for-generatin) and [that](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first).

The first link points to a suggestion about using sequences as primary keys, which seems like something you might want to do instead given your example code.

The second link points to a suggestion about generic handling of default values, which is currently not supported either, but would be another potential starting point toward adding support for what you need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bummi: Thanks for you comment, I updated the answer in an attempt to convey the gist of the linked suggestions. Note though that as they are merely suggestions for the framework, they are not really part of the answer (which is very simply "No"), only pointers of potential interest.