# Entity Framework null should invoke SQL default on insert/update

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF6, during insert/update, I'd like to be able to invoke the DB default logic on null but override that default if I pass in a value.

Currently it seems I only have two mutually exclusive options:

1. Out of the box a null passed in is written to the record
2. If I change the entity field property to "Computed" on the EF model it uses the DB default logic to populate (eg getdate()) - but ignores what I pass in

This is a DB first project using .NET Framework 4.6

Use cases:
Created / Modified date time columns in the DB defaulting to getdate()
Defaulting other non-null fields

There are old posts that this can't be done ([4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531240/entity-framework-database-defaults-on-inserts-allow-updates)) and then a post from this summer that it had been resolved in .NET Core, but no info on the details and if the same resolution is also available in .NET Framework.

Comment: In an old project of mine, I resolved it by setting the `DateTime` property nullable and added in migration `defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"`. I used two different columns, `InsertedDateTimeUtc` and `UpdatedDateTimeUtc` to know when it was added and when it was updated. The update value was set by my own in entity's repository.
I would suggest to use two separate columns too to have more precise information and avoiding your issue.

Comment: So your default value on the database is `getdate()` for the columns.

Comment: Yes, but only for the insert column. The update column is set by my own, but you could set up an interceptor to have it DRY.

Comment: The only solution I see is using database triggers.

Comment: Did not find a solution; so for CreatedDate I set it in the model to Computed; for ModDate, I inherit the relevant API models from IModDate which has that one property and then in the Add/Update operations I can use this line: var md = (T as IModDate); if (md!=null) md.ModDate = DateTime.Now;